# another duplicate list item removal challenge

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow

I have 61 lists in my site collection.

1 list is the Master and contains all the selectable data.
60 lists lookup the data in the master.

Users select an item and populate the relevant list numbers 1-60

How can I remove, either through the workflow of PowerShell, the item from the Master once it's been chosen?

This is being used as a method for 600 users to book a seat on one of 60 tables :-)

Many thanks for looking!

Comment: I've tried thinking about how to go about doing this and am failing, hence the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it...

I have a master Guests List with all 600 guests and a "BOOKED" column. This is NO by default.

For each table there is a single list and in each list there are 10 columns representing the 10 seats at the table, there is an 11th (hidden) column which allows a character entry to give me an EDITABLE item.

I have created an InfoPath form for each List/Table. There are 10 fields which have a filtered lookup to only display items from the Guest List where "BOOKED = NO"

When a guest selects a table they are editing an existing item rather than adding a new one. This was important for the InfoPath form.

Once a guest is added workflow then changes their BOOKED status to YES, thus preventing tem from being displayed in the filtered data source.

So in a nutshell for 600 seats there are 60 lists/tables and 10 columns/seats per list.

The next challenge I have is that InfoPath displays the line item ID rather than the guests name... Articles I have read have not worked for my form.